# Why Magento is preferable with LAMP?

Tags: performance, wamp, linux

As I researched everywhere all the developers prefer LAMP for Magento framework. What if we use WAMP? or is there any specific reason to use LAMP? 
If the answer is yes, please state some benefits/ advantages in Magento with LAMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento itself officially only supports a Linux based stack - see the [System Requirements here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html).

I have heard of others using Windows for Magento so my suggestion is to go with whatever works best for you. Especially now that Windows ships with a [Linux subsystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about) prior objections might me a moot point.

Comment: yeah exactly, even though magento itself suggests LAMP stack some of my colleagues are using Windows with WAMP installed. The thing is, I found that both are comparatively same. Since magento officially requires Linux based stack and that is where I thought  there might be some advantages. Also as you said Windows 10 now come up with Linux as subsystem.

Thank you for your thought @Kristof at Fooman